# Play an audio file repeatedly with fast button clicks

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm tring to provide audio feed back on a button using html5 audio.

It works fine when clicking slowly, but when clicking the button faster it misses some of the clicks.

http://jsfiddle.net/sWsTb/

**HTML**

```
<div id="count">0</div> 
<button>Click</button>
```

**JS**

```
var snd = new Audio("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14037764/Development/jsfiddle/click2.mp3");

var count = 0;
$("button").click(function () {
    snd.pause();
    snd.currentTime = 0;
    snd.play();
    count++;
    $("#count").text(count);
    return false;
});
```

After adding *snd.pause();* and *snd.currentTime = 0;* lines, it's better but still misses some of the fast clicks. Is there any way to fix that?